# How to get a batch file's cmd window to close after it's done its job?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, visual-studio-code

I'm sorry to repeat-post but I've tried most solutions I've seen on here and none have worked. Currently the way I use VS Code is by a batch file that navigates to the directory I like to work out of and then runs a command to launch it. The original file looked like this:

```
@echo off
d:
cd c++
code .
pause
```

Once VS Code launches though, the cmd prompt lingers. I assumed first it was my use of `pause`, so I swapped that to `exit`. No dice. So I took to here, saw someone suggested I append `start` to the `code .` line. Still, nothing worked. At this point, I saw another post saying that it could be getting "stuck" so I decided to throw `echo` at each point to see if that were the case, wondering where it'd stop. At this point, the file looks like:

```
@echo on
d:
echo hello1
cd c++
echo hello2
start code .
echo hello3
exit
```

Not only did this still not close the cmd terminal, but it also isn't echoing anything at all? I'm sure it's something small but I'm just too new to this to see. Thank you for your help.

Comment: The batch file should at least give you `echo hello1`, `hello1`, `cd c++`, `echo hello2`, `hello2` and `start code .` (probably more, but that as a minimum). Show us your `VS` code to launch it, probably the problem is there.

Comment: What is the lone period supposed to be there for, _(`code .`)_? `d:` isn't a command, if you wanted to change the current directory to `D:\C++`, then that's a single command, not two, i.e. `CD /D "D:\C++"` or `PushD "D:\C++"`. However, if you open up a Command Prompt window and enter `start /?` you'll note that you can change the current directory as part of that command, _(`/D` option)_. However your issue is more likely that `code` is really `code.cmd`, _(which in turn runs `code.exe`)_, this means that if you wish your batch file to return to the `pause` or `exit`, you should `Call Code`.

Comment: I don't know what the lone period is for, I'm pulling it from [this Microsoft guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw) and it works. d: *does* work for me to change the drive I'm working out of, but I had no clue you could make that one line long - I appreciate the info :)

Code is definitely code.bat, I wrote it myself and I've opened/edited it plenty of times by now to have noticed if it weren't a batch file.

Stephan - what do you mean by my "VS code"? Do you mean the .vscode folder?

Comment: Whether you're using the `code.cmd` file created as part of the Windows install process, or the `code.bat` file you wrote yourself, the method of invoking it, doesn't change, you still `Call` it, if you wish the script to continue with one or more commands upon completion.

Comment: Also if the period is supposed to be opening VS Code in the current working folder, _which becomes your "workspace"_, then it seems as if you could simply use this as your first line, `@Call code.bat D:\C++`, adding the full or relative path to `code.bat` as necessary and double-quoting one or both of those paths, should they contain potentially poisonous characters. Obviously I would recommend that you include a `Pause` or `Timeout` command after your second line, `@Echo The call has completed`, so that you have an opportunity to read that before the script `Exit`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [taskkill](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/taskkill) command to close the command window.
The first parameter of the [start](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/start) command is the title of the window to create. 
You could specify a unique string there and call for `taskkill` with `/FI` parameter.

```
start "vs_run_unique_title" code "d:\some_code_path"
taskkill /FI "WindowTitle eq vs_run_unique_title" /F /T
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`start`](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html) command:

```
@echo off
...
start "" code .
```

Your `start` syntax is incorrect. The first parameter specifies the title. So you start a cmd with title "code"

Comment: The first parameter isn't inherently the title, but the first set of encountered quotes _is_ the title regardless of where in the command those quotes are found.